# No content length specified warning appearing when I try to upload an object in s3 bucket with a java code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, inputstream

When I try to upload any object which have size in MB I get this warning "warning: no content length specified for stream data. stream contents will be buffered in memory and could result in out of memory errors." and then my code is abruptly ended. I tried saving the contents in a temp file and then uploading it with the help of multipart upload but it also doesn't seem to work.

```
InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();
                    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                            .withRegion("eu-central-1")
                            .build();
                    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                    metadata.setContentType(part.getContentType());
                    logger.log("setting metadata");

                    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, fileName, inputStream, metadata);
                    s3Client.putObject(request);
                    logger.log("putting in S3 bucket");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [S3 warning: "No content length specified for stream data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967067/s3-warning-no-content-length-specified-for-stream-data)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#setContentLength-long- obviously. Read the javadoc for this setContentLength

Comment: Yeah I saw that link but as you see in the comments it was not much helpful. When I added the buffer limit it caused it gave an error that expected limit is less than actual limit.

Comment: I read the document but as you can see in my code I have my data in inputstream and there's no way to find the accurate limit in such case.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other question using byte array to get the content length did helped with the warning but in case the size of the object was greater than 1MB, lambda would end. I had to change the lambda timeout to 2 minutes as the transfer would not complete in 15s when object is greater than 1 MB. Sharing snippet of my code also in case anyone stumble upon this question.

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        metadata.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        metadata.setContentType(part.getContentType());
```